# Convert String to JSONArray

Tags: java, json

I checked JSON is valid or not. The website says valid.

[my JSon](http://bagistest.tev.org.tr/Hastane.asmx/HastaneListesi)

Here is my JSONfunction.
I edited my function like this:

```
public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        JSONArray jArray = null;

        // Download JSON data from URL
        try {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
        }

        // Convert response to string
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
               System.out.println("sb"+sb);
            is.close();
            result = sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }
        JSONArray myArray = null;
        result = result.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
        StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(result);

        try {
            myArray = new JSONArray(result);System.out.println(myArray.get(0));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return myArray;
    }
}
```

In my function `jArray` is null. `result` is same as my JSON. How can I convert `string` to `JSONArray`. My json file look like this:
[json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoJ3H.png)

```
"[{\"Id\":1005,\"Sehir_id\":\"1\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane1\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1007,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1008,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1009,\"Sehir_id\":\"3\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1010,\"Sehir_id\":\"4\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1011,\"Sehir_id\":\"12\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"test\",\"Aciklama\":\"test\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1012,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"İstanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Aciklama\":\"İstanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1013,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"AMERİKAN HASTANESİ (NİŞANTAŞI )\",\"Aciklama\":\"AMERİKAN HASTANESİ (NİŞANTAŞI )\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1014,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1015,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"23\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (MASLAK)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (MASLAK)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1016,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (FULYA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (FULYA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1017,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (BAKIRKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (BAKIRKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1018,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KOZYATAĞI)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KOZYATAĞI)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1019,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"KADIKÖY ŞİFA HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"KADIKÖY ŞİFA HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1020,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (GAYRETTEPE)\",\"Aciklama\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (GAYRETTEPE)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1021,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (ÇAĞLAYAN)\",\"Aciklama\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (ÇAĞLAYAN)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1022,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ŞİŞLİ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ŞİŞLİ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1023,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ATAŞEHİR)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ATAŞEHİR)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1024,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"49\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"EGE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"EGE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1025,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"50\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"9 EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (İNCİRALTI )\",\"Aciklama\":\"9 EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (İNCİRALTI )\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1026,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ŞİFA ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ŞİFA ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1027,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"45\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEDİKAL PARK HASTANESİ (KARŞIYAKA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEDİKAL PARK HASTANESİ (KARŞIYAKA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1028,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ANKARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ İBNİ SİNA HASTANESİ (ALTINDAĞ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ANKARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ İBNİ SİNA HASTANESİ (ALTINDAĞ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1029,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"HACETTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (SIHHIYE)\",\"Aciklama\":\"HACETTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (SIHHIYE)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1030,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"BAYINDIR HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"BAYINDIR HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1031,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"T.O.B.B. ETÜ HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"T.O.B.B. ETÜ HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1032,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Haydarpaşa Numune Eğitim Hastanesi\",\"Aciklama\":\"Haydarpaşa Numune Eğitim Hastanesi\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1033,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"GÜNGÖREN KOLAN HASTANESİ\",\"Aciklama\":\"GÜNGÖREN KOLAN HASTANESİ\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1034,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"KOLAN HASTANESİ (GÜNGÖREN)\",\"Aciklama\":\"KOLAN HASTANESİ (GÜNGÖREN)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1036,\"Sehir_id\":\"1\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"asdasd\",\"Siralama\":2,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1037,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"49\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"TEST BORNOVA HASTANE\",\"Aciklama\":\"asd\",\"Siralama\":3,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false}]"
```

Output of sb is

```
sb:"[{\"Id\":1005,\"Sehir_id\":\"1\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane1\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1007,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1008,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1009,\"Sehir_id\":\"3\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1010,\"Sehir_id\":\"4\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1011,\"Sehir_id\":\"12\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"test\",\"Aciklama\":\"test\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1012,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Ä°stanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Aciklama\":\"Ä°stanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1013,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"AMERÄ°KAN HASTANESÄ° (NÄ°ÅANTAÅI )\",\"Aciklama\":\"AMERÄ°KAN HASTANESÄ° (NÄ°ÅANTAÅI )\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1014,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESÄ° (KADIKÃY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESÄ° (KADIKÃY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1015,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"23\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESÄ° (MASLAK)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESÄ° (MASLAK)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1016,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESÄ° (FULYA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESÄ° (FULYA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\
```

Comment: Post Your JSON here

Comment: It is not showing complete JSON.

Comment: I edited my question. @ParagJadhav

Comment: A JSON Object should not start and end with `double quotes`

Comment: I cannot change json file. How should I change my code? @ParagJadhav

Comment: Copy and paste your JSON here, that way I can help you better

Comment: I added my JSON. Thanks for your help! @ParagJadhav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just instantiate a `JSONArray` with String content, e.g.:

```
String string = "[{\"Id\":1005,\"Sehir_id\":\"1\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane1\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1007,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1008,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1009,\"Sehir_id\":\"3\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1010,\"Sehir_id\":\"4\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1011,\"Sehir_id\":\"12\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"test\",\"Aciklama\":\"test\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1012,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"İstanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Aciklama\":\"İstanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1013,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"AMERİKAN HASTANESİ (NİŞANTAŞI )\",\"Aciklama\":\"AMERİKAN HASTANESİ (NİŞANTAŞI )\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1014,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1015,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"23\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (MASLAK)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (MASLAK)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1016,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (FULYA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (FULYA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1017,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (BAKIRKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (BAKIRKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1018,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KOZYATAĞI)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KOZYATAĞI)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1019,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"KADIKÖY ŞİFA HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"KADIKÖY ŞİFA HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1020,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (GAYRETTEPE)\",\"Aciklama\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (GAYRETTEPE)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1021,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (ÇAĞLAYAN)\",\"Aciklama\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (ÇAĞLAYAN)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1022,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ŞİŞLİ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ŞİŞLİ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1023,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ATAŞEHİR)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ATAŞEHİR)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1024,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"49\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"EGE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"EGE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1025,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"50\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"9 EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (İNCİRALTI )\",\"Aciklama\":\"9 EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (İNCİRALTI )\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1026,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ŞİFA ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ŞİFA ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1027,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"45\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEDİKAL PARK HASTANESİ (KARŞIYAKA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEDİKAL PARK HASTANESİ (KARŞIYAKA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1028,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ANKARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ İBNİ SİNA HASTANESİ (ALTINDAĞ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ANKARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ İBNİ SİNA HASTANESİ (ALTINDAĞ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1029,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"HACETTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (SIHHIYE)\",\"Aciklama\":\"HACETTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (SIHHIYE)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1030,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"BAYINDIR HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"BAYINDIR HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1031,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"T.O.B.B. ETÜ HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"T.O.B.B. ETÜ HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1032,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Haydarpaşa Numune Eğitim Hastanesi\",\"Aciklama\":\"Haydarpaşa Numune Eğitim Hastanesi\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1033,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"GÜNGÖREN KOLAN HASTANESİ\",\"Aciklama\":\"GÜNGÖREN KOLAN HASTANESİ\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1034,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"KOLAN HASTANESİ (GÜNGÖREN)\",\"Aciklama\":\"KOLAN HASTANESİ (GÜNGÖREN)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1036,\"Sehir_id\":\"1\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"asdasd\",\"Siralama\":2,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1037,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"49\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"TEST BORNOVA HASTANE\",\"Aciklama\":\"asd\",\"Siralama\":3,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false}]";
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(string);
System.out.println(array.length());
```

**Update**

Based on question edit, it seems that `sb` does not have full content compared to `result`. `sb` String terminates at `UpdaterUID` whereas actual `result` terminates the object and an array and hence, it fails while parsing `sb`.

So, it looks like the buffer is not getting flushed or is not having full content in itself. I would probably try changing the approach to read the `InputStream` into a `String` and see if that makes any difference, e.g. something like this:

```
public String convertStreamToString(java.io.InputStream is) {
    java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(is).useDelimiter("\\A");
    return s.hasNext() ? s.next() : "";
}
```

**Another Update**

Looks like you need to trim the quotes from the beginning and end and un-escape the quotes from the response String to make it work. Below snippet works fine:

```
URL url = new URL("http://bagistest.tev.org.tr/Hastane.asmx/HastaneListesi");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(
            connection.getInputStream()));
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
    response.append(inputLine);

in.close();
String trimmedResponse = response.toString().substring(1, response.toString().length() - 1);
trimmedResponse = trimmedResponse.replace("\\\"", "\"");
System.out.println(trimmedResponse);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(trimmedResponse);
System.out.println(array.length());
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I do this, I can convert `string` to JSONArray. I don't understand why I cannot convert `result ` to JSONArray. Can you help me?

Comment: @user8654574 could you try printing out the result and post it in question?

Comment: When I try your solution to my `result`,  JSONArray will be null. `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: Maybe the `String` you are trying to parse is not actually a json. If you copy paste the above snippet into a `main` method, it would work. This suggests that the `result` value is different from the one posted in question.

Comment: @Darshan you're right, result might be different that's why OP is not able to acheive the expected result

Comment: I understand now. Yes, my result is null. But I do not understand why, because `sb` is same as my json file.

Comment: @user8654574 Try doing `System.out.println(sb);` after while loop and check the value?

Comment: I tried many solution to get sb, but I can't. When I debug sb is full content.

Comment: @user8654574 try using `sb.toString()` instead of result and see if that makes any difference?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @user8654574 Okay, give me the url used in question and I will provide another approach to get the `JSONArray` from it.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it try using,

You can validate your JSON [here](https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cbee5227). It is also a wise choice to remove escape characters from JSON.

Link to [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/o/Downloadorgapachecommonslangjar.htm).

```
String test = "\"[{\"Id\":1005,\"Sehir_id\":\"1\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane1\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1007,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane3\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1008,\"Sehir_id\":\"10\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Aciklama\":\"deneme hastane4\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1009,\"Sehir_id\":\"3\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeyetest hastane\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1010,\"Sehir_id\":\"4\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Aciklama\":\"Luckyeye hastanee\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1011,\"Sehir_id\":\"12\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"test\",\"Aciklama\":\"test\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1012,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"İstanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Aciklama\":\"İstanbul Test Hastanesi\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1013,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"AMERİKAN HASTANESİ (NİŞANTAŞI )\",\"Aciklama\":\"AMERİKAN HASTANESİ (NİŞANTAŞI )\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1014,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1015,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"23\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (MASLAK)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (MASLAK)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1016,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (FULYA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (FULYA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1017,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (BAKIRKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (BAKIRKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1018,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KOZYATAĞI)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ACIBADEM HASTANESİ (KOZYATAĞI)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1019,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"KADIKÖY ŞİFA HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Aciklama\":\"KADIKÖY ŞİFA HASTANESİ (KADIKÖY)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1020,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (GAYRETTEPE)\",\"Aciklama\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (GAYRETTEPE)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1021,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (ÇAĞLAYAN)\",\"Aciklama\":\"FLORENCE NİGHTİNGALE (ÇAĞLAYAN)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1022,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ŞİŞLİ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ŞİŞLİ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1023,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ATAŞEHİR)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEMORİAL HASTANESİ (ATAŞEHİR)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1024,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"49\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"EGE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"EGE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1025,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"50\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"9 EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (İNCİRALTI )\",\"Aciklama\":\"9 EYLÜL ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (İNCİRALTI )\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1026,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ŞİFA ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ŞİFA ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (BORNOVA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1027,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"45\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"MEDİKAL PARK HASTANESİ (KARŞIYAKA)\",\"Aciklama\":\"MEDİKAL PARK HASTANESİ (KARŞIYAKA)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1028,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"ANKARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ İBNİ SİNA HASTANESİ (ALTINDAĞ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"ANKARA ÜNİVERSİTESİ İBNİ SİNA HASTANESİ (ALTINDAĞ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1029,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"HACETTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (SIHHIYE)\",\"Aciklama\":\"HACETTEPE ÜNİVERSİTESİ HASTANESİ (SIHHIYE)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1030,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"BAYINDIR HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"BAYINDIR HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1031,\"Sehir_id\":\"2\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"T.O.B.B. ETÜ HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Aciklama\":\"T.O.B.B. ETÜ HASTANESİ (SÖĞÜTGÖZÜ)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1032,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"Haydarpaşa Numune Eğitim Hastanesi\",\"Aciklama\":\"Haydarpaşa Numune Eğitim Hastanesi\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1033,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"GÜNGÖREN KOLAN HASTANESİ\",\"Aciklama\":\"GÜNGÖREN KOLAN HASTANESİ\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1034,\"Sehir_id\":\"8\",\"Ilceid\":\"1\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"KOLAN HASTANESİ (GÜNGÖREN)\",\"Aciklama\":\"KOLAN HASTANESİ (GÜNGÖREN)\",\"Siralama\":1,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1036,\"Sehir_id\":\"1\",\"Ilceid\":\"\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"deneme hastane\",\"Aciklama\":\"asdasd\",\"Siralama\":2,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false},{\"Id\":1037,\"Sehir_id\":\"15\",\"Ilceid\":\"49\",\"Hastaneadi\":\"TEST BORNOVA HASTANE\",\"Aciklama\":\"asd\",\"Siralama\":3,\"Minbagis\":null,\"Minsure\":null,\"CreatorUID\":null,\"CreationDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"CreatorIP\":null,\"UpdateDate\":\"\\/Date(-62135596800000)\\/\",\"UpdaterUID\":0,\"UpdaterIP\":null,\"Deleted\":false}]\"";
test = test.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(test);
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(test);
System.out.println(myArray.get(0));
```

Update:

```
result = result.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", ""); 
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(result);
JSONArray myArray = new JSONArray(result);
System.out.println(myArray.get(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! When I use your `String test`. It works. But I want to use with my `result` string. How can I do that? @Parag Jadhav

Comment: Do the same operations on `result`

Comment: I've updated my code. Accept it as answer if it solves your problem

Comment: I tried what you exactly did. `Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value  of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray`

Comment: Pleas update your code, let me see what are you trying

Comment: I understand now. Yes, my `result` is null. But I do not understand why, because sb is same as my json file.